# Recreate Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I have to take a Docker image from a vendor site and then push the image into the private repository (Artifactory). This way the CI/CD pipeline can retrieve the image from the private repository and deploy the image.

What is the best way to achieve it, do I need to recreate the image?

Comment: what do you mean by download the image manually from vendor ? what is the file you got from there ?

Comment: The url provided by the vendor contains the image file

Comment: and what is this file tar binary ... ?

Comment: this file doesn't have any extension, how to identify if its a binary or tar?

Comment: is it Dockerfile ? can you edit with a text Editor ?

Comment: Its kind of archive, I can open the file using 7Z. It contains several directories and each directory contains layer.tar, json and version file. The root folder contains manifest.json

Comment: try this : `docker load < name_of_file` then check `docker images` to see if the image is in your local system

Answer (score 0):

steps:

1. take a pull of the base docker image from vendor.
2. create new folder for your new docker image.
3. create a Dockerfile.
4. write your base docker image.
5. do the changes inside this folder.
6. build new docker image using cmd.
7. push the image into docker hub.

refer this (not exactly according to your need, but this helps): https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-create-docker-images-with-dockerfile/

for cmd and Dockerfile changes, refer docker office doc site

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We can't do a docker pull from  the vendor site as its not a repository. We can manually download the image. In that case also the above steps works

Comment: manually download the image or setup the docker registry at the vendor site

Comment: then skip the step#1 and follow the rest

Comment: thank you, can you please help me to understand how in the docker file we can refer to the downloaded image and can recreate the image. Sorry if I am not clear

Comment: FROM {imagename}, to listout the downloaded docker image using cmd docker images

Answer (score 0):

I believe its a tar or zip file that they have given you by `docker save` and `docker export`.
You can perform below operations.
1. Perform `docker load < file.tar` - You will get the image name that's loaded. Note down the name.
1. Download the tar or zip file to your local.
2. Perform `cat file.tar | docker import image_name_that_you_noted_above`
3. You are good to use the image now. `tag` it to your repo and `push`, or directly run using `docker run`